# *.app is missing and can't build my project

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I cleaned my project and *.app file under product folder removed.

now I can't make a build of my project

error :

```
Showing Recent Messages
:-1: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Driver-deamxuxagojqlbazpefgfkovfwid/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Driver.app/Info.plist' (in target 'Driver')
```

The error is pretty clear. It can not read `info.plist` from Driver.app because there is no Driver.app

How can I build or make one?

This is what I've done till now :

- Tried to build from product -> build
- Clean from product menu
- Clean cocoa pods and install again
- Clean all caches

Comment: Delete the derivedData folder "/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"
and build again

Comment: i have.not working

Comment: you better create a new project and copy everything from here

Comment: esaiest way  ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

1. Navigate to the project (select it in the Project navigator)
2. Select the application target in the list of targets
3. Click the Build Settings tab
4. Under the Packaging section, make sure the `Info.plist` file is
   properly set to the location/file name

Comment: it is set to /Users/myuser/ios/driver/Driver/Driver/Info.plist  which is exact path

Comment: @Ryan110 could you please brief your procedure, so that it could help other at some point?